# How to debug multi thread using GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I am debugging "Veracrypt" with gdb because I want to know the order of the functions that are called when the volume is mounted using Veracrypt. Since Veracrypt use the multi-threads, I modified MakeFile by writing the gdb option "-g" and used some command such as `thread apply all bt full`, `set follow-fork-mode child`, and so on. Also I tried to attach the thread using thread ID such as `sudo gdb -p [process ID]`.

So I can debug the code of Veracrypt, but I can't debug some code.

Using GDB, I have verified the thread ID of the multi-thread to be used when Veracrypt is running(Volume Mount and Dismount process) and gdb displayed the thread ID of the created threads as shown below.

```
[New Thread 0x7fffedf3e700 (LWP 5071)]
[New Thread 0x7fffed73d700 (LWP 5072)]
[New Thread 0x7fffecf3c700 (LWP 5073)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe7fff700 (LWP 5074)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe522f700 (LWP 5075)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe4a2e700 (LWP 5076)]
[New Thread 0x7fffdf568700 (LWP 5077)]
[New Thread 0x7fffded67700 (LWP 5078)]
[New Thread 0x7fffde566700 (LWP 5079)]
[Thread 0x7fffded67700 (LWP 5078) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffded67700 (LWP 5081)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc9798700 (LWP 5082)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc8f97700 (LWP 5083)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc3fff700 (LWP 5084)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc37fe700 (LWP 5085)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc2ffd700 (LWP 5086)]
[Thread 0x7fffc3fff700 (LWP 5084) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc2ffd700 (LWP 5086) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc37fe700 (LWP 5085) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffded67700 (LWP 5081) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc8f97700 (LWP 5083) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc9798700 (LWP 5082) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffc9798700 (LWP 5087)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc8f97700 (LWP 5088)]
[New Thread 0x7fffded67700 (LWP 5089)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc37fe700 (LWP 5090)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc3fff700 (LWP 5091)]
[Thread 0x7fffc9798700 (LWP 5087) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc8f97700 (LWP 5088) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc37fe700 (LWP 5090) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc3fff700 (LWP 5091) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffde566700 (LWP 5079) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffde566700 (LWP 5092)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc3fff700 (LWP 5093)]
[Thread 0x7fffc3fff700 (LWP 5093) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffded67700 (LWP 5089) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffded67700 (LWP 5094)]
[Thread 0x7fffded67700 (LWP 5094) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffded67700 (LWP 5095)]
[Thread 0x7fffded67700 (LWP 5095) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffedf3e700 (LWP 5071) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffed73d700 (LWP 5072) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffe7fff700 (LWP 5074) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffecf3c700 (LWP 5073) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffe522f700 (LWP 5075) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff7fc4a40 (LWP 5066) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffdf568700 (LWP 5077) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffe4a2e700 (LWP 5076) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 5066) exited normally]
```

And I used "fprintf(..)" and "getpid()" to write the thread ID that executes each function when Veracrypt is running(Volume Mount and Dismount process) in the file. (I also have a question in this part. Because in the function code that can not be debugged with gdb, the "printf(...)" function does not print the value to the terminal, but in the function code that can be debugged, the value is printed to the terminal.)

When I checked the thread ID that executed the function I wanted to debug in the file generated by using "fprintf" function, it was not in the list of the thread ID that generated by gdb(above code) and had a value larger than the thread ID in the list. (In this case(above code), the thread ID executing the function that I want to debug is 5098).

I want to debug some function such as `CoreUnix.cpp::MountVolume` and `CoreLinux::MountVolumeNative`. How can I debug these functions with gdb?

Answer (score 1):

> I used "fprintf(..)" and "getpid()" to write the thread ID that executes each function

Note that for non-ancient versions of GLIBC (which you appear to be using), `getpid` returns process ID, not thread id. You probably want to use [gettid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html) instead.

> Because in the function code that can not be debugged with gdb, the "printf(...)" function does not print the value to the terminal, but in the function code that can be debugged, the value is printed to the terminal.)

What *exactly* do you mean by "function that can not be debugged"?

I suspect that you are able to set breakpoints on that code, but the breakpoint is never hit. If that's the case, it sounds like you are debugging the wrong process. In general, `set follow-fork-mode child` rarely is what one wants: processes that create children often create more than one child, and it's exceedingly rare to always want to debug the very first child at each `fork`.

Comment: I also used "gettid()" but it's value was same as that of getpid(). 
And the precise meaning of "function that can not be debugged" is that it is a function code of Veracrypt that does not stop at a breakpoint by using the options used for debugging multi thread but run during Veracrypt's mount process.